# Isolation of unit tests with fastapi and postgres

Tags: postgresql, unit-testing, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I have a small problem. I have an api with several endpoints, and several models. And so I decided it was better to create automated tests to speed up the work of developers who put their hands on this project in the future. However, I'm having trouble isolating these tests.

I need to isolate them, because the data that is saved in the tests goes straight to the production database and that is not recommended at all. So I would like to find a way to isolate this data.

I've already tried creating a separate database for these tests. However, I am faced with the problem that the model is pointing directly to a specific database schema in production.

I've also tried to create a docker instance, but it didn't work, I don't know if it's because my database is asynchronous.

Well here is my unit test:

```
import pytest
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from database.conn import Base
from app.models.finance.bills_to_pay_models import BillsToPay  
import os
from sqlalchemy.future import select
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession, create_async_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

USER = os.getenv('DB_USER')
PASSWORD = os.getenv('DB_PASSWORD')
HOST = os.getenv('DB_HOST')
NAME = os.getenv('DB_NAME_TEST_OMIE')

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = f"postgresql+asyncpg://{USER}:{PASSWORD}@{HOST}/{NAME}"

engine = create_async_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL, echo=True)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(bind=engine, class_=AsyncSession)

@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
async def test_db():
    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.create_all)
    async with SessionLocal() as session:
        transaction = await session.begin()
        yield
        await transaction.rollback()
        await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.drop_all)  
        await session.close()

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_bills_to_pay_create(test_db):
    async with SessionLocal() as session:
        new_category = BillsToPay(
            example1="Teste",
            example2=12,
            example3=1,
            

        )

        try:
            session.add(new_category)
            await session.commit()

        except Exception as e:
            await session.rollback()
            raise e


        result = await session.execute(select(BillsToPay).filter_by(example1="Teste"))
        category_from_db = result.first()[0]
        if not category_from_db:
            raise ValueError("Error")

        assert category_from_db.example1 == "Teste"
        assert category_from_db.example2 == 12
        assert category_from_db.example3 == 1
        

        await session.close()
```

And here is my model:

```
from database.conn import Base
from sqlalchemy import String, Integer, Column 

class BillsToPay(Base):
    __tablename__  = 'BillsToPay'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'finance'}

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    example1 = Column(String, nullable=True)
    example2 = Column(Integer, nullable=True)
    example3 = Column(Integer, nullable=True)
```

I would just like a tip. Which way to go. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see you taged fastapi, did you try to follow fastapi official testing doc? https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/testing-database/#testing-a-database.
You just need a new db session (engine of your choice) and a test client instance, it allow you to test through your router directly

Comment: Thanks, work in here